# Multi line Json read using USQL Custom extractor

Tags: u-sql

I could not find proper solution to make use Newtonsoft JsonExtractor to parse Input file with new line delimiter.

From the Newtonsoft JsonExtractor I can read the first line successfully when exploded with "$.d.results[*]" but it's not moving to the next line,

As the data is >4MB for each row, can't extract as text. So parsing need to be performed using custom extractor to proceed.

Sample Input:

```
{"d":{"results":[{"data":{"Field_1":"1","Field_2":"2"},"Field_3":"3","Field_4":"4"}]}}                      
{"d":{"results":[{"data":{"Field_1":"11","Field_2":"21"},"Field_3":"31","Field_4":"41"}]}}
{"d":{"results":[{"data":{"Field_1":"12","Field_2":"22"},"Field_3":"32","Field_4":"42"}]}}
```

Expected Output:

```
Field_1|Field_2|Field_3|Field_4
1      |2      |3      |4
11     |21     |31     |41
12     |22     |32     |42
```

USQL Code:

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY IF NOT EXISTS [Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats] FROM @"Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.dll";
CREATE ASSEMBLY IF NOT EXISTS [Newtonsoft.Json] FROM @"Newtonsoft.Json.dll";

REFERENCE ASSEMBLY [Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats];
REFERENCE ASSEMBLY [Newtonsoft.Json];

USING Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json;

DECLARE @DATA_SOURCE string = "Input.data" ;
@SOURCE =
    EXTRACT Field_1 string,
            Field_2 string,
            Field_3 string,
            Field_4 string
    FROM @DATA_SOURCE
USING new JsonExtractor("$.d.results[*]");
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering your **source input** as below, i.e. more than one JSON document in a file.

```
{
    "d": {
        "results": [
            {
                "data": {
                    "Field_1": "1",
                    "Field_2": "2"
                },
                "Field_3": "3",
                "Field_4": "4"
            }
        ]
    }
}                      
{
    "d": {
        "results": [
            {
                "data": {
                    "Field_1": "11",
                    "Field_2": "21"
                },
                "Field_3": "31",
                "Field_4": "41"
            }
        ]
    }
}
{
    "d": {
        "results": [
            {
                "data": {
                    "Field_1": "12",
                    "Field_2": "22"
                },
                "Field_3": "32",
                "Field_4": "42"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

> // if more than one JSON document in a file

The JSON assembly includes a **MultiLevelJsonExtractor** which allows us to extract data from multiple JSON paths at differing levels within a single pass. See the underlying code and inline documentation over at [Github](https://github.com/Azure/usql/blob/master/Examples/DataFormats/Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats/Json/MultiLevelJsonExtractor.cs).

Use it by supplying multiple levels of Json Paths. They will be assigned to the schema by index.

The code snippet shows the MultiLevelJsonExtractor in action.

- The first parameter (rowpath) specifies the base path to start from.
- The second parameter (bypassWarning) is expecting a boolean value.
  True = If path isn't found: don't error, return null. False = If path
  isn't found: error.
- The third parameter (jsonPaths) is a list of JSON paths starting at
  the base path otherwise the extractor will recurse to the top of the
  tree to locate it.

**in your case....**

```
   @json =
    EXTRACT
        Field_1 string,
        Field_2 string,
        Field_3 string,
        Field_4 string,
    FROM
        @DATA_SOURCE
    USING new MultiLevelJsonExtractor("d.results[*]",
        true,
        "data.Field_1",
        "data.Field_2",
        "Field_3",
        "Field_4",
         );
```

Comment: Thanks for your findings but I dont find this working. Reference provided in GitHub uses Multilevel json sample which is actual Json file with multi line but here I got multi line Json array but not Json file itself (if you notice there is no comma between the lines). While attempting I got error "Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content: {. Path '', line 2, position 0"